# Chrome Hover bug - possible fixed position, or nth child cause

Tags: css, google-chrome, navigation, hover, css-selectors

I Am experiencing a weird bug with chrome, I have my nav fixed to top and have a hover affect applied using first-child, nth-child, and last child. Hover effect works at first but as soon as you scroll it is as if the hover scrolls up with it. Only having problems with chrome, it works fine in firefox, IE9+, safari 5+. Thanks in advance!

Here is the link where the demo site can be seen http://www.digitaldripmedia.com/vans

HTML --

```
<header id="header">
  <nav class="nav-global-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="images/warped-tour-logo.png" alt="Vans Warped Tour Logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-global">
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Lineup</a></li>
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

SCSS --

```
.nav-global-container {
    width: 100%;
    height:9em;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 800;
    background-color: $black;
}

.logo{
    width: 6.5em;
    margin:$center;
    margin-top:1em;

    img{
        width: 100%;
    }

}

.nav-global{
    @extend %clearfix;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-items{
    display:block;
    width:33.3333333%;
    padding:5px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    float:left;
    @include font-style('tex',16px,white);
    text-align: center;


    &:first-child{
        border-top: 4px solid $cool-gray;
            @include transition(background-color .3s ease);
            &:hover {
                background-color:$cool-gray;
            }
    }

    &:nth-child(n+2){
        border-top: 4px solid $red;
        @include transition(background-color .3s ease);
            &:hover {
                background-color:$red;
            }
    }

    &:last-child{
        border-top: 4px solid $navy;
        border-right:none;
        @include transition(background-color .3s ease);
            &:hover {
                background-color:$navy;
            }
    }


    a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        color:white;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to be working as expected for me on OSX Chrome 37.0.2062.94

Comment: it could be a z-index bug?

Comment: @haxxxton what OSX you running, I had my friend tell me his was working on OSX Chrome 37 as well, I am running OSX 10.7.5 Chrome37 and I get no luck

Comment: @Timothy That was one of my first guesses I removed the z-index completely off of the .nav-global-container and get no hover at all. I was thinking possibly the z-index on the background video?

Comment: make a js fiddle out of your code

Comment: @VinceBrown OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Will try a bit more but if you remove the video the hover works, so something there that's cuasing it

Answer (score 0):

Setting `z-index` on .nav-global-container to 3, .video-dot-overlay to 2 and .fullscreen-video to 1 solves it for me(tried in dev tools)